# How can I rename index.html file in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, config, svelte, rollup

So I have two components in one svelte app that I run separately using separate rollup.config files. But the problem is they both render on index.html so both render the same thing. How can I use a different index.html file for both?

Technically I know they should be independent separate apps. But it's an iframe that renders the rest of the components so it's difficult to manage and run two apps. Is there a hack or a way to rename index.html?

Comment: To confirm, you are using plain svelte and not sapper?

Answer (score 1):

Svelte doesn't use your index.html, your index.html uses svelte.
Simply make a new html file and point it to the other bundle.